# How to uninstall an app which restarts the phone when uninstalling it?

Tags: malware, uninstallation

This app named [Handwriting Fonts for Samsung, Oppo and HTC phones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monotype.android.font.glad.handwritten) is acting like a malware. Whenever I try to uninstall it, my phone restarts (or probably reboots) and the app doesn't get uninstalled. When I checked the reviews, there were other people too having the same issue.

I have tried uninstalling it from Google Play also. I have tried forcing stopping it; clearing data and then uninstalling it; using safe mode to uninstall it. No progress.

Comment: Enable Developer mode and Android Debug Bridge (adb) on your device and connect to to a PC with adb tools installed. Then use `adb logcat` to see if there is a log entry that explains why the device is rebooting.

Comment: When using ADB, you could also try `adb uninstall com.monotype.android.font.glad.handwritten`. As ADB has "elevated privileges" (not quite root, but still more than "average"), this might have a chance. Apart from that: Have you installed the app, or did it come pre-installed on your device?

Comment: I have installed it from Google Play